# Getting Contacts through IMAP using JavaMail / Android in Exchange

Tags: java, android, exchange-server, imap

I've set up my android program to contact the exchange server and check for a list of new emails (along with sending), but surely there is a way to access the exchange global list?

I'm not too sure how it's done at this moment, in the mean time I will be installing a traffic monitoring program to break down the request headers and see all the information which is passed, but if anyone has any insight to this, all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some [code](http://code.google.com/p/corporateaddressbook) that queries the GAL using ActiveSync. Works on Android.

Comment: I'll take a look at it tomorrow!  Thank you@

Answer (score 1):

IMAP, at least in its Exchange incarnation, does not support anything but the regular messages and does not process any contacts, be that the Contacts folder in your mailbox or GAL.
Is using Outlook an option?
Can you use any mail apps that use ActiveSync to talk to Exchange (Mail App in iOS does)?

Comment: It's in the GAL... I have conjured up a work around that works in Java, but the issue lies when I try to port it over to android as the javax.naming package doesn't exist.